# Splitting, Aggregating then streaming writing on one big file using Apache Camel

Tags: java, performance, apache-camel

I have a large database from which i load huge records. I process them in a batch mode using the splitter and agregator patterns.

The step where i'm stuck is the streaming of each batch to one json file where i want them all to be stored. Here are the steps :

1. Fetch records from DB
2. Process them as batchs of N
3. Each processed batch is written in a same big json file (missing step)

I tested this solution with the Append option from File2 but it does write multiples arrays in an an array. I could flatten this JSON but it takes me to one question.

How to stop the route from running knowing that i have two requirements :

1. After run the batch, the size at the start is not necessarly the same on in the end.

I tried to work with completionFromConsumer but does not work with quartz consumers.

I have this route :

```
   from(endpointsURL))
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "Start fetching records")
        .bean(DatabaseFetch, "fetch")
        .split().method(InspectionSplittingStrategy.class, "splitItems")
        .aggregate(constant(true), batchAggregationStrategy())
        .completionPredicate(batchSizePredicate())
        .completionTimeout(BATCH_TIME_OUT)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "Start processing items")
        .bean(ItemProcessor, "process")
        .marshal()
        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, true)
        .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("extract.json")))
        .to("file:/json?doneFileName=${file:name}.done")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "Processing done");
```

The problem here is as i supposed, my extract.json gets overwritten with every batch processed. I want to append every batch after an other.

I have no clue how to design and which pattern to use to make this possible. [Stream](https://camel.apache.org/stream.html) and [File](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html) have good features but in which fashion i can use them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the route strategy using only a splitting stategy :

```
from(endpointsURLs.get(START_AGENT))
            .bean(databaseFetch, "fetch")
            .split().method(SplittingStrategy.class, "splitItems")
                .parallelProcessing()
                .bean(databaseBatchExtractor, "launch")
            .end()
            .to("seda:generateExportFiles");

    from("seda:generateExportFiles")
            .bean(databaseFetch, "fetchPublications")
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .to("direct:generateJson", "direct:generateCsv");

    from("direct:generateJson")
            .log("generate JSON file")
            .marshal()
            .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, true)
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("extract.json")))
            .to("file:/json?doneFileName=${file:name}.done")
            .to("direct:notify");

    from("direct:generateCsv")
            .log("generate CSV file")
            .bean(databaseFetch, "exportCsv")
            .to("direct:notify");

    from("direct:notify")
            .log("generation done");
```

The important class `SplittingStrategy` :

```
public class SplittingStrategy {

        private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 500;
        private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        public Collection<List<Pair<Integer, Set<Integer>>>> splitItems(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> itemsByID) {
            List<Pair<Integer, Set<Integer>>> rawList = itemsByID.entrySet().stream()
                    .map((inspUA) -> new ImmutablePair<>(inspUA.getKey(), inspUA.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return rawList.parallelStream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(pair -> counter.getAndIncrement() / BATCH_SIZE)).values();
        }
    }
```

With this strategy instead of using aggregate to re-assemble items. I embeeded the aggregation strategy as part of the splitting :

1. Transform my hashmap into an Iterable List> to be returned by the split method (c.f [Splitter with POJO](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-UsingaPojotodothesplitting))
2. Split items in batches of 500 items size with a groupingBy of my initial list stream.

Give a comment or your opinion about it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Camel to append to the file if it exists, add `fileExists=Append` as option to your file endpoint.

Comment: I wonder if the JSON file would be still valid with this option. I hope it append object with invalidate the file syntax

Comment: Yeah that is something to consider.

Comment: I we supposed, it appends multiples arrays one after another.

Comment: I kept searching these days about a way to notify about the completion on all the process before flatten my final output file. OnCompletion.onWhen do seems to fit

Comment: I can't still figure out what completion would apply to it. I'm thinking of a dynamic size but i don't know if i can pass a set property throght multiples routes ?

Comment: Some insights would be great guys